# How to refer Attribute parameter in qi::grammar which is passed by qi::parse_phrase

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I am trying to refer `Attribute`   (*i.e. semantic_action class in my code*) parameter passed to `qi::parse_phrase` in my grammar. But not able to figure out how to achieve that. As a work around, I have declared a member variable of type `Attribute` in my grammar class.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_utree.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace bs = boost::spirit;

struct semantic_action
{
    std::vector<int> tokens;

    void add_tokens(int a)
    {
        tokens.push_back(a);
        std::cout<< "Matched integer: " << a <<'\n';
    }
};

template<typename Iterator>
struct my_grammar : public qi::grammar<Iterator,semantic_action(),bs::ascii::space_type>
{
    my_grammar() : my_grammar::base_type(start,"MY")
    {
        start = qi::int_
                [
                 boost::phoenix::bind(
                     &semantic_action::add_tokens,
                     &this->sem_act_,// referring member variable, but want to refer Attribute
                     qi::_1)
                 ] % ','; 

    }

    qi::rule<Iterator,semantic_action(),bs::ascii::space_type> start;

    // referring member variable, but want to refer Attribute
    semantic_action sem_act_; /** work around **/
};

template<typename Iterator>
bool parse(Iterator & begin,Iterator end,my_grammar<Iterator> const & grammar)
{

    semantic_action a;
    auto r = qi::phrase_parse(begin,end,grammar,bs::ascii::space,a);

    for(auto const & item : grammar.sem_act_.tokens)
        std::cout<<"::parse():  grammar.sem_act_.tokens -- "<<item<<'\n';
    for(auto const & item : a.tokens)
        std::cout<<"::parse(): a.tokens -- "<<item<<'\n';
    return r;
}


int main()
{
    std::string input = "12,13,24,34";

    auto it = input.begin();
    my_grammar<decltype(it)>  g;

   if(::parse(it,input.end(),g) )
    {
        std::cout<<"parse success\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"parse failed\n";
    }
    std::cout<<"Unparsed input => "<< std::string{it,input.end()}<<'\n';
}
```

Comment: [`qi::_val`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal.attributes)?

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: @GautamJha http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/phoenix.html and e.g. http://boost-spirit.com/home/2011/02/26/using-_val-in-top-level-semantic-actions/